# Upload speed of larger files using PHP is very slow

Tags: php, upload

I've tested this on localhost so bandwidth isn't an issue. I searched Google and the solution I ran into most is using a Flash/Ajax tool to avoid this problem.

Case 1:

```
file: test.jpg
size: 183kb
result: < 1 s
```

Case 2:

```
file: test.mp3
size: 2.4mb
result: > 10 min
```

Comment: call these; what are they saying? echo ini_get("post_max_size"); echo "<br>".ini_get("memory_limit");

Comment: 20M, 128M. 
i just tried uploadify, 30mb file, only 10s